# integrate stand-alone YAF into DNN

Tags: sql, dotnetnuke, yaf

I have an active YAF Forum and the members of the forum are demanding to integrate it into DNN. Can somebody who has done this before(Integrate a existing stand-alone YAF into DotNetNuke in a way so that there is no data-loss) help me out? I will be very thankful if somebody can tell me the exact steps.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

There is a module for YAF to be a module for dnn (http://dnnyafnet.codeplex.com/)

However as to migrating an existing YAF to DNN might not be that easy.

YAF has a mass user export import I would use that for your base DNN install (look at one of the import modules on the store)

After that comes the grunt work - you might try installing the YAF module on a fresh dnn install and seeing if you can simply import the info or connect to the current database scheme of the YAF.